# wordpress problem of slowing down and not showing the page well

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I use METALOGIC THEME the problem is that the first page doesn't appear well to the user in addition to being slow

wordpress problem of slowing down and not showing the page well

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons for this but my first instance is to ensure you don't have unnecessary plugins installed which can slow down your site.

Use [Google PageSpeed Insights](https://pagespeed.web.dev/) to analyse what could be wrong with your page. It will give you a good indication on what's affecting page load speed

Use a Good Caching plugin. [W3 Total Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/) is my personal favourite

Comment: I updated all the plugin and the problem still again pageinsights give me these errors on red Ensure text remains visible during webfont 
load Does not use passive listeners to improve scrolling performance
Image elements do not have explicit width and height
Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy

Comment: in addition I add this cache plugin W3 total cache but the problem still when I tried to change the theme the problem is fixed but what I want is to keep the some theme

Comment: can you tell me all the plugins you are using or give a link so I can check and give you a clearer idea

Comment: I am assuming you mean this theme: http://webdesign-finder.com/metalogic/. I ran page speed insights on this theme, and it is not the best for performance both on mobile and desktop. You will need to go through the improvements and do what is necessary to get the performance better alternatively use a different theme

Comment: Thank you bro now I'm waiting for the response from the support

Comment: I wont be able to fix the whole website by just looking at it because there are might be many reasons why you are having problems and you are better off hiring a developer to fix these issues for you as StackOverflow is not for that. First of all, I would fix all of the console errors you are getting. Then I would disable all the plugins that didn't come with the theme and then activate them one by one to see what's causing the issue.

Comment: ok bro thank you for your help I don't have time to fixe it so I 'm going to find another solution